# Where can I download Visual Studio 2017 ISO setup?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded ISO of VS 2015 Update 3. But when I getting to create UWP apps they VS says for download Windows 10SDK. But the official says that VS2015.3 is packed with all required components for UWP. But It still requires internet to download these components. I don't have the internet to download these components. I need offline components of these.  Please give me a solution.  Alongside I am installed Anniversary Update. Please give me a link to download "Tool for Universal Application Development"  offline installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution is on the ISO file you downloaded, reinstall but this time choose the custom installation when it starts and chose what and what you wish to install, don`t forget to choose the UWP button, hope this works